# a function in php

Tags: php

i have a function to validate if a email exists in a BD, if exists the registration is not permit.

The function works well, but it shows two times the message  "Your email is already registered". What is the reason of that?

```
function repetirDados($email) {
    if(!empty($_POST['email'])) {
        //Escape our posted inputs
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

        $usercheck = $email;

        $check = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email ='$usercheck'")
        or die(mysql_error());
        $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);

        if ($check2 == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            echo '<h1>Your email is already registered</h1>';
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

no problem with this

```
 function inserirDados($name, $email, $myPassword, $pass2 ) {
        if(repetirDados($email)){
            $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
            $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
            $myPassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['myPassword']);
            $pass2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass2']);

            $registerquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (name, email, pass) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."', '".$myPassword."')") 
            or die("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error());

            //let the user know of success or failure
            if ($registerquery) {
                echo '<h1>Registo efectuado com sucesso</h1>';
            } else {
                echo '<h1>Erro no registo</h1>';
            }
        }
```

Any advice? or improvement in code?

```
EDIT:
    <div id="error" class="valid">
                <ul>
                <?if(!repetirDados($_POST['email'])):?><?endif?>
                <?if(!inserirDados($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'], $_POST['myPassword'], $_POST['pass2'] )):?><?endif?>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Maybe the function is called twice? Or after return false someone thought to add the output again? Please show the code that calls the function. The problem probably is there

Comment: Where is the function called?

Comment: Here's a tip. First of all learn how to use PDO and prepared statements :)

Comment: First you need to learn how to prevent SQL injections http://bobby-tables.com/php.html

Comment: edited code, thanks, i will search about sql injection

Comment: why do you pass $email as a parameter to the function if you store the post value in the function?

Comment: this question should be deleted as too localized, bot nobody would bother ever.

Comment: @Osman what's wrong with injections here? Why post nonsense comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is this

```
<div id="error" class="valid">
            <ul>
            <?if(!inserirDados($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'], $_POST['myPassword'], $_POST['pass2'] )):?><?endif?>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

as the function inserirDados call the function repetirDados i don't need to repeat. Is the reason

```
  <div id="error" class="valid">
                <ul>
                <?if(!repetirDados($_POST['email'])):?><?endif?>
                <?if(!inserirDados($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'], $_POST['myPassword'], $_POST['pass2'] )):?><?endif?>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

First look at the code doesn't seem wrong. Did you echo out `$check2` to see what it returns? if it returns 0 then there is a problem with your query

also you store `$_POST['email']` in `$emai`l and then in `$usercheck`, there is no need to store it in a second variable (unless you are planning on doing something with it first?)

also always concatenate like you did in the second code block

```
mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email ='".$usercheck."'")
```

**EDIT:**

Further more you should always use full php tags `<?php ?>` and not the shorttags `<? ?>`. The shorttag for php depends on the configuration of the server.

and maybe you should consider this approach:

**In your function**

```
 if ($registerquery) {
                return '<h1>Registo efectuado com sucesso</h1>';
            } else {
                return '<h1>Erro no registo</h1>';
            }
```

**Where you call your function:**

```
<?php
   if(!$message = repetirDados($_POST['email'])):
     echo $message; 
   endif;
if(!$message = inserirDados($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'], $_POST['myPassword'], $_POST['pass2'] )):
   echo $message;
endif;
?>
```

NEVER PRINT something inside your function, always return a mesage

Comment: if i put an echo"something"; it is shown two times, then the function is always repeated for any reason